# Existing Podfile found in directory

Tags: terminal, cocoapods

Using pods, Terminal gave me this message "[!] Existing Podfile found in directory" (there is not) when running "pod init" in directory.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by reloading the directory path. Running "cd /Users/x/Desktop/x" again, and then "pod init".